# Use of Symlinks in Magento

Tags: magento2, symlinks

I am studying use of `symlinks` in Magento 2 and also read some articles on it. But I am not clear about what they are . And also what does the option `Allow Symlinks` in Magento 2 backend does? Can anyone offer me a proper explanation. Some of the links which I referred to are

https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-symlinks-for-modules/

https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/How-to-use-Magento-2-with-no-symlinks-anywhere/td-p/48402